# SharePoint 2010 Foundation on Windows 7 - missing SharePoint Foundation Search

Tags: search, sharepoint-foundation, windows-7

I've installed SharePoint 2010 Foundation on Windows 7 based on [this](http://sharepointjungle.com/2010/03/06/install-sharepoint-2010-on-windows-7/) article.
When I do a search in one of the team sites I've setup, I received this error ***The search request was unable to connect to the Search Service.***
When I go to the Central Administration -> Manage Service Application this is what I saw
[image: Manage Service Application]

As you can see there is no SharePoint Foundation Search running.
How do I add the SharePoint Foundation Search Service. Thanks. Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My teammate found the answer, this is how to solve it. Open SharePoint 2010 Management Shell and run this script

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures
```

Now go to the Central Administration -> Manage Services on Server and you'll find that the SharePoint Foundation Search is running.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I have absolutely no idea why is it as it is, but I managed to solve the same problem by .... entering SharePoint Foundation Help Search....

Basically when you click to stop Help Search, the option SharePoint Foundation Search is back but the Help Search is gone... Start it again and the options switch back to as they were... Just as if the labels were changing for some reason I can't comprehend

Comment: Bingo! My head was all over!

Answer (score 0):

Not that familiar with SharePoint foundation but the search service application might need to be provisioned first?

- [Step by step how to provision the search service application](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2009/11/23/step-by-step-provisioning-the-search-service-application.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the effort, but I'm looking for SharePoint Foundation Search and not SharePoint Search Service